# Visualize time series data

Tags: python, time-series, visualization

I have a time series data set with 3 parameters and 5 dates per time point which I would like to visualize. The problem is that the date time points (year) are not equal over the parameters:

```
ID       Year       A          B        C
ID1      1971       5          100      0.5
ID1      1972       6          102      0.4
ID1      1981       4          101      0.6
ID1      1991       5          103      0.5
ID1      1993       2          104      0.4
ID2      1971       4          100      0.9
ID2      1973       4          108      0.8
ID2      1981       5          109      0.7
ID2      1991       3          106      0.6
ID2      1993       3          103      0.5
```

What would be the best way to visualize such data?

Comment: It depends on what type of analysis you would like to perform and what question you want to a answer. Also, it's unclear to me what you mean by "5 dates per time point". Can you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks, I mean that each ID has 5 dates but they do not overlap. At the moment the only I idea I have is to show a heap map of all unique years.

Answer (score 1):

Color line for each `ID` differently . The gaps in the data should show up in the graphs as-is .

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.line(df, x="Year", y="A", color='ID')
fig.show()
```

Comment: There are too many data points, just chaotic lines one over the other...

Comment: Try plotting in log scale to see if that helps. Pass  log_y = True as an argument in px.line()